# Which plist contains macOS Mail SMTP server list?

Tags: macos, email, smtp

Question about macOS Mail, under Monterey: I want to backup the list of outgoing servers, which has some obscure problems. After an extensive search (at least it seemed extensive), I can't find the plist file that contains the list. Does anyone know where to find it? Many thanks for any help.